# Count amount of (sub) tests run in python unittest test case

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, data-driven-tests

For a repetitive unit test, I have several test cases in a Yaml-File (`resources/test_cases.yml`), which looks like this:

```
scenario_1:
  test_cases:
    expected:
      - 1
      - 1
      - 1
      - 1

scenario_2:
  test_cases:
    expected:
      - 1
      - 1
      - 1
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
import ddt
from unittest import TestCase

@ddt.ddt
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @ddt.file_data("resources/test_cases.yml")
    def test_data(self, test_cases):
        for test_case in test_cases:
            with self.subTest():
                expected_result = test_case["expected"]
                self.assertEqual(expected_result, 1)
        # after that, I would like to ensure that 2 scenarios where tested
        # and 7 tests ran in total
```

as specified in the code comments, I'd like to ensure that every test in the yaml file ran (and none was skipped, for whatever reason).

#### Question

Is there a way to find out:

- How many test cases were inserted through the decorator
  `@ddt.file_data("resources/test_cases.yml")` (in the example: 2)
- How many subtests were actually run for one test case (in `scenario_1`: 4, in
  `scenario_2`: 3)
- How many tests actually ran in total (7)

Of course I could introduce a counter-variable, but that seems cumbersome and I would assume that theres a way to find this out.
I know there is method [`countTestCases()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=counttestcases#unittest.TestSuite.countTestCases) but as stated in the docs, it always yields 1, no matter where I put it.

I already found two related questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500267/python-unittest-count-tests) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305235/python-unittest-counting-the-number-of-tests)) but it both do not make use of subtests and an external file. Also, it seems quite cumbersome and I was thinking that my problem should have quite straightforward solution